# Users Sign-In report doesn't work for azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

According to this FAQ section: [What reporting and auditing features does Azure AD B2C provide?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs#what-reporting-and-auditing-features-does-azure-ad-b2c-provide-are-they-the-same-as-in-azure-ad-premium), the Sign-in report available in the Azure Active Directory should reflect users sign-in events. Shouldn't it?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The latest advice, as documented by [Azure AD B2C UserJourney Reports API is now deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2018/02/05/azure-ad-b2c-userjourney-reports-deprecated-use-audit-events-reporting-instead/), is to use the "B2C" category of the Azure Active Directory audit logs.

These audit logs contain application, authentication, directory, and other related events.

The audit logs can be accessed via the Azure Portal or [the Azure Active Directory audit API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-audit-reference).